# Need to use regex to extract a part of a string

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm a regex noob that's trying to use the regexp_extract() function in data studio to extract part of a string. Could you help me out?

I need to extract the part of the string that comes after 'May'. Everything before 'May' is exactly the same across all campaigns.

I've tried googling the solution and killed a lot of time on regexer.com but i can't figure it out

```
Current Campaign Name:                       
Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MayComedy Movie Fans18-24 
Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MaySouth Asian Film Fans18-24 
Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MayCricket Enthusiasts18-24   
Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MayMotorcycle Enthusiasts18-24    

Expected Campaign Names:
Comedy Movie Fans18-24
South Asian Film Fans18-24
Cricket Enthusiasts18-24
Motorcycle Enthusiasts18-24
```

EDIT: I'm trying to use this in data studio in the `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campaign,"regex_code_here")` function. I think the acceptable syntax is re2.

Comment: What language and regex engine are you using?

Comment: What's wrong with `/May(.+)$/`?

Comment: Depending if your undisclosed language supports lookbehinds, it would be pretty simple: `(?<=\bMay).+$`

Comment: I'm using google data studio so it's going to be re2 and i guess javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may actually use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here to remove all before and including `May`:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign, '.*May', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3KPj6z/2):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is this:

```
(?<=May).*$
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/zwEAfY/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace

- `^.*?May` - Match everything up-to first occurrence of `May`
- "$`" - replace with portion that follows substring [**Ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

  ```js
  let arr = ["Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MayComedy Movie Fans18-24","Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MaySouth Asian Film Fans18-24","Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MayCricket Enthusiasts18-24","Xxxxx_xxxxx_PKN_Trueview_24th MayMotorcycle Enthusiasts18-24"]

  let op = arr.map(str=> str.replace(/^.*?May/g, "$`"))

  console.log(op)
  ```